# Sync two different performances of the same melody using Dynamic Time Warping results

Tags: python, audio, signal-processing

I am aligning two recordings of the same melody, once played on bassoon and once on viola. Using dynamic time warping as described [here](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/craffel/alignment-search/blob/master/overview.ipynb), I have as an output an array of indices of the frames of the audio which I should concatenate in order to match the target.

I tried synthesizing the time-adjusted audio using a phase vocoder. However, all the libraries I have found (in Python) only change the tempo of a recording according to a fixed ratio.

Does anyone know of a phase vocoder which would take as its argument an array of frame indices? Thoughts on any other approaches would be appreciated.